# Split the [minecraft] tag into Java and Bedrock Editions

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

There are two editions of Minecraft, Java Edition (the original, written in Java, obviously) and Bedrock Edition (a rewrite in C++). From a normal gameplay perspective, these are basically the same game, but from a technical perspective, they have absolutely nothing in common. The programming languages, data formats, and basically everything else relevant on Stack Overflow are completely different. As such, I think it would be beneficial to split [minecraft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) into [minecraft-java-edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition) and [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition).

Comment: I didn't even realize Minecraft had relevant parts for Stack Overflow!

Comment: My primary concern here is a very practical one: what are the chances that people will be able to tag their questions correctly? Will they actually know which edition they're using?

Comment: @CodyGray I think they will. It's on the main menu in the game itself, right under the name, and all of the tools and documentation is already specialized enough that to get literally anywhere at all with modding, you need to know the edition. (And at least most people have installed someone else's mod before they've tried to make one of their own.)

Comment: I admire your optimism. ;-)

Comment: How do you plan on applying the correct tag to each of the ~2300 [Minecraft] questions?

Comment: Not to be that guy... but according to Google, there are right now in fact 16 or 17 editions of Minecraft, not just two. Even the bedrock version exists in multiple iterations - and as far as I know the Windows 10 bedrock edition does not in fact name itself as such anymore, it just says "Minecraft" on the title screen in recent versions. You are referring to Minecraft games which can be modded. I do believe the Minecraft education edition needs to be listed in there as well.

Comment: @Cerbrus Java Edition has significantly more programming capability for users than Bedrock Edition, so most of our Minecraft questions are about it. For any Minecraft questions that are also tagged with Java, Maven, Gradle, Bukkit, Spigot, Minecraft Forge, Eclipse, IDEA, or Netty, we could retag them to Java Edition with almost 100% confidence, leaving us with very few to have to look at manually.

Comment: That's fair enough.

Comment: @Gimby All of those other editions use the C++ codebase, so I'd say we should just lump all of them under Bedrock Edition. And in general, they all have rather limited potential for modding, so there aren't many questions about them here.

Comment: As a heavily-invested lurker of the tag (as well as bukkit, forge, etc) I wouldn't terribly mind it, but I think we'd need to address the base Minecraft tag being a bit of a hot mess currently. I don't think we need to go back and pull out obvious bedrock posts, but it's being used a lot as a kind of meta tag. I think we'd need to keep minecraft for "How do I accomplish this (lighting | rendering | etc) like Minecraft does?" where the platform doesn't matter, and have -java -bedrock -forge -fabric etc for specific platform questions?